# TraciMobility::getExternalId error when adding custom module into Veins_Inet example (Omnet++)

Tags: c++, network-programming, omnet++, veins, inet

I am attempting to add a new custom RSU module (extending AdHocHost) into the Veins_Inet example. Here is my updated scenario (with 1 RSU).

```
network TestScenario {
submodules:
    radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
    manager: VeinsInetManager;
    node[0]: VeinsInetCar;

    // added rsu
    rsu: VeinsInetRSU;
connections allowunconnected:}
```

I also updated the ini file so that the RSU mobility is

```
*.rsu.mobility.typename = "inet.mobility.static.StationaryMobility"
```

and the RSU application is barebones with minor implementation:

```
*.rsu.app[0].typename = "practice.veins_inet.VeinsInetRSUSampleApplication".
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TraCIMobility::getExternalId called with no external id set yet.
```

In the example, the VeinsInetManager is managing the cars with TRACI. Here is the ned file associated with the manager. The source file has 2 functions, pre-initialize module and update module position.

```
simple VeinsInetManager extends TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd {
parameters:
    @class(veins::VeinsInetManager);}
```

How can I add a custom module into the scenario without raising any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application might be inheriting from `VeinsInetApplicationBase`, which calls TraCI methods (that fail for nodes that are not a TraCI-managed vehicle). See also [its source code](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.cc#L66).

To be doubly-sure, run your simulation in debug mode, turn on `debug-on-errors`, and check the stack trace to see where the call is coming from.